# Inno Setup Icon blurred

Tags: inno-setup

I am facing couple of issues as follows -

1. After setting [Setup]SetupIconFile=full icon path and using a standard 128 pixel icon to make Inno setup installer. 
   Here, I found - Inno setup installer file icon, Welcome page top left corner small icon and taskbar icon are blurred on resolution 1920 X 1080 & 125% dpi which is default for my machine.
2. Also I found WizModernImage.bmp & WizModernSmallImage.bmp images are little bit blurred on all installation pages.

Please let me know -

a. Any way to show proper image at top left corner small icon.

b. Any setting / option to disable or do not show welcome page top left corner small icon.

c. Anyway to show WizModernImage.bmp & WizModernSmallImage.bmp images as per resolution / dpi.

Thank you.

Regards,
Shashi

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

In order to set custom BMP for each DPI you will have to override the default behavior. 
Simple example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: ".\custom_bg\*"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy nocompression; 
;sample names, corresponding to code: 
;wizard_96.bmp, wizard_120.bmp, wizard_144.bmp, wizard_168.bmp
;wizard_small_96.bmp, wizard_small_120.bmp, 
;wizard_small_144.bmp, wizard_small_168.bmp

[Code]
var
  DPIValString: String;

procedure CheckDPI;
    var
      CurrentDPI, StandardDPI, MediumDPI, LargeDPI, UltraDPI: Integer;
    begin
      // Get the current DPI
      CurrentDPI  := WizardForm.Font.PixelsPerInch;

      // Store defaults determined from Windows DPI settings
      StandardDPI := 96;  // 100%
      MediumDPI   := 120; // 125%
      LargeDPI    := 144; // 150%
      UltraDPI    := 168; // 175% introduced by Windows 10 

      if (CurrentDPI >= StandardDPI) and (CurrentDPI < MediumDPI) then 
      begin
          DPIValString := '_96';
      end
      else if (CurrentDPI >= MediumDPI) and (CurrentDPI < LargeDPI) then
      begin
          DPIValString := '_120';
      end
      else if (CurrentDPI >= LargeDPI) and (CurrentDPI < UltraDPI)then
      begin
          DPIValString := '_144';
      end
      else if (CurrentDPI >= UltraDPI) then
      begin
          DPIValString := '_168';
      end;
    end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CheckDPI;
  ExtractTemporaryFile('wizard' + DPIValString + '.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('wizard_small' + DPIValString + '.bmp');
  if (FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\wizard' + DPIValString + '.bmp')))
   and (FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\wizard_small' + DPIValString + '.bmp'))) 
   then begin 
    with WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage do
      Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\wizard_small' + DPIValString + '.bmp'));
    with WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage do
      Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\wizard' + DPIValString + '.bmp'));
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Thank RobeN for your reply and it works for WizardBitmapImage. But do not find any way to do the same way for WizModernSmallImage.bmp. Please let me know about how to set WizModernSmallImage.bmp as per the DPI. Thanks - Shashi

Comment: Simply add specific images for `WizardSmallImageBitmap` - I have updated the example above.